# Java UI on top of Ruby script

Tags: java, ruby, swing, javafx, jruby

I've been searching for answer without any luck for the below problem:

- I have a quite lengthy ruby script which if you run in terminal(MAC) requires multiple inputs from user throughout execution. I would like to put on top of that script a Java UI - Swing or JavaFX so that the input is done via the Java UI throughout execution.

Is there any way to achieve this, how do you track  the state of the script execution and how do you pass a input from Java UI to ruby script once required.

Now this is might be broad question so here is the example below how it would look like more or less:

I have a test.rb file with the below:

```
puts  "enter your name:
@name = gets
puts @name
...
```

So Java would look something like:

```
String command = "ruby test.rb";
Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
run.waitFor();
...
```

So I could assign results of 'run' to the String but thats not much use.

I have looked at the JRuby but without any luck also (Maybe just dont understand it).

Many Thanks!

Comment: What about Zenity or one of its [mac alternatives](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/73613)?

Comment: thanks @AndreLDM, I will check it out.